# Validar o input com os valores populados pelo ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Opa! mais uma que to levando uma surra.

Tenho um input que é auto populado via ajax, conforme vai digitando o ajax busca e vai listando resultados em `<li>` numa `<div>` abaixo do input. Tipo a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, o código hoje, permite que o usuário submeta o formulário com qualquer coisa escrita no input.

E eu quero que ele **tenha que clicar obrigatoriamente em alguma coisa da listagem**, se não, não será possível avançar.

Meus códigos.

**O input:**

```
<div class="col-md-5 text-center">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg text-muted mb-3" type="text" id="busca" autocomplete="off" name="busca" placeholder="Digite Bairro ou Cidade">
    <div id="buscalist" style="position:absolute;z-index:99;"></div>
</div>
```

**O script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#busca").on("keyup", function(){
        var busca = $(this).val();
        if (busca !=="") {
          $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            type:"POST",
            cache:false,
            data:{busca:busca},
            success:function(data){
              $("#buscalist").html(data);
              $("#buscalist").fadeIn();
            }  
          });
        }else{
          $("#buscalist").html("");  
          $("#buscalist").fadeOut();
        }
      });
      $(document).on("click","#buscas li", function(){
        $('#busca').val($(this).text());
        $('#buscalist').fadeOut("fast");
      });
  });
</script>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
include_once ("config.php");
    if (isset($_POST['busca'])) {
        $output = "";
        $busca = $_POST['busca'];
        $query = "SELECT dataatualizacao, bairro, cidade FROM imoveis WHERE bairro LIKE '%$busca%' OR cidade LIKE '%$busca%' AND (dataatualizacao >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ".$diasatualizados." DAY)) GROUP BY bairro";
        $result = $MySQLiconn->query($query);
        $output = '<ul id="buscas" class="list-unstyled" style="background-color:#fff;padding:8px;color:#6c757d;cursor: pointer;">';        
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $output .= '<li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> '.ucwords($row['bairro']).', '.ucwords($row['cidade']).'</li>';
            }
        }else{
              $output .= '<li><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Conteúdo não encontrado</li>';
        }
        
        $output .= '</ul>';
        echo $output;
    }
?>
```

E ja testei algumas coisas dentro do meu conhecimento, mas só gerei mais problemas.
Tipo, fugiu a lógica. Por isso venho aqui, pedir mais uma ajuda.
Se puderem me dar um norte, será de grande valor.
Grato

Answer (score 0):

Uma solucao simples seria colocar um `hidden` input que sera populado com o que o usuario selecionar.

```
<div class="col-md-5 text-center">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg text-muted mb-3" type="text" id="busca" autocomplete="off" name="busca" placeholder="Digite Bairro ou Cidade">
    <input id="busca_result" type="hidden">
    <div id="buscalist" style="position:absolute;z-index:99;"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on("click","#buscas li", function(){
    $('#busca').val($(this).text());
    $('#busca_result').val($(this).text());
    $('#buscalist').fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Entao vc valida o form para ver se o result foi clicado, algo tipo:

```
$('#meuForm').submit(function( event ) {
    if(!$('#busca_result').val()){
         event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: É isso irmão! Funcionou! Preciso só apresentar algo tipo "Você precisa clicar abaixo" ou nem precisa, muito bom!. Obs: sou novato, não consigo nem pontuar a resposta. Gratidão irmão.

Comment: Coloque um label no seu input para informar o usuario, UX... Para tbm forcar o usuario a clicar vc pode limpar o campo de busca se usuario nao selecionar da sua lista... veja [jQuery focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) ... algo tipo `$( "#busca" ).focusout(function() { if(!$(this).val()){ $(this).val('') }})`

Comment: Gratidão caiovisk.